# How many gflops does 4 way sli titan x pascal have?

Tags: graphics-cards

If you where to combine 4x titans how many teraflops do you get?  [just a pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqxBJ.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The theoretical single-precision rating of a single Titan X Pascal is 11 TFLOPS per [the media (ArsTechnica)](http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2016/07/gtx-titan-x-pascal-specs-price-release-date/).

If you multiply 11 by 4, and assuming you have enough PCIe lanes to support all of these GPUs under full load, and assuming you have enough CPU and memory bandwidth to "feed" a real workload to each of these cards maxed out, that would be **44** TFLOPS single-precision.

You will never be able to use this kind of raw horsepower for gaming, even with an ideal workload on DirectX 12's [EMA](http://arstechnica.com/gaming/2016/02/directx-12-amd-and-nvidia-gpus-finally-work-together-but-amd-still-has-the-lead/). The only way you could hope to utilize it all would be with a very high-end CPU (or perhaps multiple Xeon E5 CPUs), high clock rate DDR4 for system memory, and using OpenCL or CUDA on embarrassingly parallel single-precision workloads.